# How to set resource key to anchor HREF tag on aspx page in asp.net localization

Tags: asp.net, localization, anchor, globalization, resx

I want to set `Resource key` to the below `href` of `anchor tag` and used below two approaches.

```
<a href='<%$ Resources:Resource, NewsletterArchive %>' class="button action blue"> </a>
```

AND

```
<a href='<%=CommunityServer.Web.ResourceLibrary.Resource.NewsletterArchive %>' class="button action blue"> </a>
```

But, no luck..
Got the below error

> ```
> >  Literal expressions like '<%$ Resources:Resource, NewsletterArchive
> > %>' are not allowed. Use <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$
> > Resources:Resource, NewsletterArchive%>" /> instead.
> ```

Please, help.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, but this worked for me:

```
<a href="<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Branding, footerAboutLink%>" />">
<asp:Label ID="footerAbout" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Branding, footerAbout%>"></asp:Label></a>
```

Comment: this worked great!  Thanks for providing a working sample.  For anyone else using this approach...the name 'Branding' in the example would be the name of the resource file within the App_GlobalResources folder in your project.  The complete file name is actually 'Branding.resx' which provides default context, in my case 'en-US'.  To localize to Spanish create another file in the same folder named 'Branding.es.resx'.  The value 'footerAboutLink' is the 'Name' within the resource file with a value you wish to see in the alt, title or in this case the url tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach should work correctly. But if it is not working, you may use code behind.

Your design page:

```
<a id="hprLink" runat="server" class="button action blue">It is my link</a>
```

Your code behind:

```
hprLink.Attributes.Add("href", GetGlobalResourceObject("your_resource_file", "your_resource_key").ToString());
```

Comment: <a href="<%GetGlobalResourceObject("your_resource_file", "your_resource_key").ToString() %>" class="button action blue">It is my link</a> try out this approach

Comment: tried but gets an err `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @PranavBilurkar have you appointed your resource file name and key correctly?

Comment: `<a href="<%GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "Pets").ToString();%>" runat="server" class="button action blue" runat="server" id="href"><span
                class="label"><%=CommunityServer.Web.ResourceLibrary.Resource.NewsletterArchive %></span> </a>` @khazratbek